What is this white debris/mess in this Chevy Bolt's hood compartment, and what to do about it?
This Chevy Bolt 2017 Premier had its battery replaced a few months ago and has barely been driven since. Before battery replacement, CarFax indicates it sat with a dealership for 2.5yrs from 2021-2023 with minimal mileage, probably during GM's buyback/recall efforts.
Taking a close look under the hood, I notice some white insulation-like material on either side of the (engine compartment?) On passanger side it is tucked in neatly and on the driver's side (where the charger port is) it looks as if it were a messy spray foam job, with maybe some brown organic matter - is this sign of rodent damage? I've read rodents find the warmth of the charger port area appealing?
I just bought this car from a used car dealership. I'm swinging by there for something else today and will ask them about it but I wanted to get a sense of what it might be first. I imagine they won't do much for me. Actions I'm considering are doing nothing (I've driven it about 100mi now without issue), or use a shop vac to suck out any loose debris, or bring it to my usual mechanic or a Chevy dealer for further inspection. For those first two options, I'd keep an eye on it and watch for rodents. It's hard to get a close look though, and while high voltage cables are sheathed, there are smaller cables I wouldn't be surprised if rodents enjoy nibbling.
Here's what it looks like on the cleaner side:

Zoom in on clean side:

Another angle zoom in on clean side:

Zoom out on messy side:

Zoom in on messy side from a few angles - it's hard to get a good picture but you get the sense of the mess and the odd brown irregular object that seems wrapped around an orange (high voltage) cable:


